# Selenium. How to close a popup if the selector is not known in advance?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, neural-network

I can’t know the selector in advance, since the site can be any that opens on the browser page of my Selenium project. How to close popup if I don't know selector?

Need a universal way to determine the element closing button the window.

I am considering the definition of a web element using a neural network, is there nothing simpler? do you know ready-made solutions for this?

Comment: Two questions: 1) by "popup" do you mean a separate popup-window, or a modal dialog on the same webpage? 2) Do I understand correctly that you're writing a Selenium tests against an unknown website?

Comment: 1) yes, modal dialog on the same webpage

2) Yes, you understand correctly, my test walks randomly on sites and does not know the exact selectors.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a list of selector for commonly used frameworks, and then remove the entire modal element with Javascript:

```
private static final String CSS_SELECTOR_BOOTSTRAP = ".modal";
private static final String CSS_SELECTOR_JQUERY = ".ui-dialog";

// TODO: extend this list as you go
WebElement modalDialog = webDriver.getElement(By.cssSelector(String.join(",", CSS_SELECTOR_BOOTSTRAP, CSS_SELECTOR_JQUERY)));
((JavaScriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].parentNode.removeChild(arguments[0])", modalDialog);
```

Comment: Sorry, but here  must specify the selector, but it is necessary that the selector to close the window is selected automatically